# How do I use a wooden shovel to only break yellow concrete powder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know how to make shovels that can break only other items, but yellow concrete powder isn't working.

It always says:

> May break: missingno

I am on 1.12.2 and the command is:

```
/give @p minecraft:wooden_shovel 1 0 {CanDestroy:["minecraft:yellow_concrete_powder"]}
```

Comment: It _always_ says `May break: missingno`

Comment: What version are you on, and what's your current command?

Comment: I am on 1.12.2 and the command is `/give @p minecraft:wooden_shovel 1 0 {CanDestroy:["minecraft:yellow_concrete_powder"]}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this: 
`/give @p minecraft:wooden_shovel 1 0 {CanDestroy ["minecraft:concrete_powder","color=yellow"]}`

Answer (score 0):

[SirBenet](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/54474/sirbenet) provides the following information from [this comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/322763/how-do-i-use-a-wooden-shovel-to-only-break-yellow-concrete-powder#comment459712_322763):

> In 1.12.2 you cannot specify only one colour of concrete powder, as all concrete powder uses the same ID (`minecraft:concrete_powder`). The NBT you have there will work in the 1.13 snapshots.